# Can I pin columns if I'm using the Shadcn Table component alone, or do I need to also use the Tanstack Table package?

Tags: reactjs, headless-ui, tanstack

I want to pin to the right an "Actions" column that contains a button in its cells. I'm using Shadcn Table component. I'm not sure if I can achieve it without the help of other packages. Is using Tanstack Table necessary?